# How do i set up proxy in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have been trying to implement proxy to my selenium webdriver. Have no idea what's wrong with my code. Any idea?

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
def open_browser():
    chromeUrl= "C:/Users/Drivers/chromedriver.exe"
    firefoxUrl= "C:/Users/Drivers/geckodriver.exe"
    edgeUrl="C:/Users/Drivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"
    print("Starting opening web browser")
    try:
        f= open('saved/proxy.txt','r')  
        proxy_ip = f.read()
        f.close()
        PROXY= proxy_ip
        print("I have download a proxy: " + PROXY)


        if len(proxy_ip) <= 1:
            print("No Proxy will be used...")
            driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path= firefoxUrl)

        else:
             webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.Edge['proxy'] = {
            "httpProxy":PROXY,
            "ftpProxy":PROXY,
            "sslProxy":PROXY,
            "noProxy":None,
            "proxyType":"MANUAL",
            "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
            "autodetect":False}
            driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.Edge(EdgeUrl))




    except:
        os.system("python proxy_request.py")
        print("Warning: No proxy")
        driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path= "C:/Users/Drivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(300)
    return driver
driver = open_browser()
url = 'htttp://www.google.com'
driver.get(url)
```

I couldn't deal with the problem. Half of the code in from official webdriver documentation, although i couldn't find one for EDGE.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

According to [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver), proxy isn't supported by edge webdriver. And it seems, MS hasn't wish to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much written in official docs to add proxies in edge webdriver. However you can use `edgeOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent=xxx")` and `edgeOptions.AddArgument("--proxy-server=xxx")` to set the proxy and user agent.

```
options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
#Here we try to set Firefox user agent...
options.add_argument("--user-agent=mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 10.0; win64; x64; rv:78.0) gecko/20100101 firefox/78.0"); 
#Change the link below for adding proxy
options.add_argument("--proxy-erver=http://user:password@yourProxyServer.com:8080");
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/376056/microsoftedgeseleniumtools-assign-a-custom-proxy.html